# CMake clang and c++0x

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

When using clang++, how can I make CMake use the `-std=c++0x` flag when compiling, but not when linking?

There are several other posts regarding using clang as compiler, but I have not found any hints on setting the c++ standard.

Here is what I tried:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(test)
add_executable(main main.cxx)
```

ClangOverride.txt:

```
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT                "-Wall -std=c99")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT          "-g")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL_INIT     "-Os -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT        "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO_INIT "-O2 -g")

SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT                "-Wall -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT          "-g")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL_INIT     "-Os -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT        "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO_INIT "-O2 -g")
SET (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT         "")
```

main.cxx:

```
int main(){ return 0; }
```

Command used to invoke `cmake`

```
CC=clang CXX=clang++ cmake .. -DCMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE=ClangOverride.txt -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Building the project:

```
VERBOSE=1 make
```

This will invoke the following two commands:

```
/usr/bin/clang++    -Wall -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cxx.o -c /tmp/asdf/main.cxx
/usr/bin/clang++    -Wall -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cxx.o  -o main -rdynamic
```

The second command results in warning because if the un-used flag: -std=c++0x

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-std=c++0x'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cxx.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Hmm, AFAIK, CMake shouldn't use compiler driver to link object files. What is `CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE` thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use ADD_DEFINITIONS("-std=c++0x") instead of setting CXX flags.

Comment: If you don't want this option to appear in C targets, you have to set it in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.

Comment: What is this? Where do I have to put it?