# CMake cross-compiling: C flags from toolchain file ignored

Tags: c, cmake, cross-compiling, flags

I use cmake for cross compiling. In my toolchain file there is a line

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=gnu99")
```

This variable is not set in CMakeLists.txt again.

When I run `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake ..` this flag is ignored.

To be more detailed: The line of `flags.cmake` shows an empty `C_FLAGS =` line.
But in `CMakeOutput.log` I can find a line `Build flags: -std=gnu99`.

I found out that a second run of `cmake ..` (same with or without toolchain file specified) fixes this problem.

But why is it not set the first time i run cmake ??

EDIT: Added MNWE

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(myproject)

SET(files src/main.c)

add_executable(myexec ${files})
```

**avr.cmake:**

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER avr-gcc)

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=gnu99")
```

Comment: Thank you! I had this exact issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've found a temporary solution by replacing the line

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=gnu99")
```

by

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=gnu99" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

Comment: It works, thank you (I added the line just after the "project" instruction)

Comment: This saved my evening.

Answer (score 18):

I just wanted to add some background information (discussed e.g. here [how to setup cmake_c/xx_flags per toolchain?](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-January/048429.html)).

In short, the `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` variables are cached by design in the `CMake<Lang>Information.cmake` scripts (meaning you could change them in CMake's GUI application after the configure step).

So you have to - if setting them in the [Toolchain](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#The_toolchain_file) file - put them in the cache first. CMake's own script (executed after the Toolchain file) does not come with a `FORCE`, so it won't overwrite it again.

Take a look into CMakeCInformation.cmake (from share\cmake-2.8\Modules):

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "$ENV{CFLAGS} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT}")
# avoid just having a space as the initial value for the cache
if(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT STREQUAL " ")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT)
endif()
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT}" CACHE STRING
     "Flags used by the compiler during all build types.")
```

As you can see, the official way to do it would be using `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT` to inject additional flags. The problem there is, that later changes in the Toolchain file would not be recognized (the cache won't be overwritten, see above).

Taken all this into account, your temporary solution is the right choice. To be really sure - because the Toolchain file is parsed twice during the Configuration/Generation process - you could even add an `UNSET` call before setting `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` in your toolchain file:

```
UNSET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS CACHE)
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=gnu99" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

Another often found solution is to use something like:

```
add_definitions(" -std=gnu99")
```

to inject compile flags (but this is not build configuration aware, as the variable definitions are). See also [CMake clang and c++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938805/cmake-clang-and-c0x)

With CMake 2.8.12 there were new commands introduced, so you could do (not tested, just to show the possibilities):

```
add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELASE>:-std=gnu99>")
add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-std=gnu99 -g3>")
```

See [What is the modern method for setting general compile flags in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995019/what-is-the-modern-method-for-setting-general-compile-flags-in-cmake) and [CMake generator expression, differentiate C / C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525047/cmake-generator-expression-differentiate-c-c-code) for more on this.