# CMake toolchain file won't use my custom CFLAGS

Tags: build, cmake

I need to write a toolchain file to configure special compiler prefix and CFLAGS on my build system. I'm trying to do it with CMake, but I'm having a hard time.

Here is an example of my toolchain.cmake file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING TRUE)
set(COMPILER_PREFIX sh4)
set(USER_ROOT_PATH /opt/st40)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${USER_ROOT_PATH})
find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER NAMES ${COMPILER_PREFIX}gcc)
find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER NAMES ${COMPILER_PREFIX}g++)
find_program(CMAKE_AR NAMES ${COMPILER_PREFIX}ar)
find_program(CMAKE_RANLIB NAMES ${COMPILER_PREFIX}ranlib)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mruntime=os21 -mboard=board_custom003024_map256_se -specs=lib/custom003024_h205_board.mem")
```

But I get this error during the compiler checks:

```
  Building C object
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2889774418.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

  /opt/st40/bin/sh4gcc -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2889774418.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -c
  /project/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c


  Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec2889774418

  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2889774418.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

  /opt/st40/bin/sh4gcc
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2889774418.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -o
  cmTryCompileExec2889774418

  sh4gcc: -mboard undefined

  gmake[1]: Leaving directory
  `/project/cmake/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
```

And on CMakeCache.txt, I can see the following variable:

```
//Flags used by the compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=
```

As you can see, it doesn't use the CMAKE_C_FLAGS variable in the sh4gcc call. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a workaround in another question. Seems that if I set CMAKE_C_FLAGS in the toolchain file like this:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mruntime=os21 -mboard=board_custom003024_map256_se -specs=lib/custom003024_h205_board.mem" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

It works the way I expect it too. This doesn't seem to have any weird side effects.

Comment: Pingback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423313/cmake-cross-compiling-c-flags-from-toolchain-file-ignored