# How to cross compile with cmake + arm-none-eabi on windows?

Tags: windows, cmake, arm, g++, cross-compiling

I like to automate the cross compiling for several projects on a Windows build server. I have some problems with the arm cross compiler. Setting it up seems a bit difficult. The cmake compiler check fails with a linking error(see below).

My experimental project looks like:

```
main.cpp - a test programm
CMakeLists.txt - the cmake build script
cmake/STM32F2xx.cmake - the special settings for the ARM STM32F2xx-series
```

I am using 3 Packages:

```
cmake-3.8.0-win64-x64.msi -cmake for windows
mingw-w64-install.exe - mingw 64 for windows
gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q1-update-win32.exe - arm x compiler
```

The main.cpp contains:

```
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
# module name
set(PrjName testPrj) 

project (${PrjName})
# module version
set(PCK_MAJOR 1)
set(PCK_MINOR 0)
set(PCK_REVISION 0)

#####################
# Features switches
#####################

#####################
# architecture
#####################
# possible values:
#   NATIVE
#   STM32F2xx

SET(Arch NATIVE CACHE STRING "Architecture")

#############################
# software stack search path
############################
SET(SWstackPath NONE CACHE STRING "software stack search path")

#############################
# software stack handling
############################
if (${SWstackPath} STREQUAL NONE)
else ()
    include_directories(${SWstackPath})
endif()

#############################
# package creation
#############################
SET(PackageFormat "DEFAULT" CACHE STRING "the format of the installation package")


########################
# define module content
########################

# MetaData header
set(testApp "testApp")

set(${testApp}_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(${testApp}_VERSION_MINOR 2)
set(${testApp}_VERSION_REVISION 3)
set(${testApp}_SOVERSION 4)

########################
# architecture handling
########################
if(${Arch} STREQUAL NATIVE)
    MESSAGE("Architecture is set to NATIVE")
else()
    include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/${Arch}.cmake)
endif()

if (${PackageFormat} STREQUAL "DEFAULT")
    if (UNIX)
        include(GNUInstallDirs)
        set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
    else ()
        set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP")
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR "bin")
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR "lib")
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIRSTATIC "lib")
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_INCLUDEDIR "include")
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_MANDIR "doc")
    endif()
elseif(${PackageFormat} STREQUAL "ZIP")
    set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR "bin")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR "lib")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIRSTATIC "lib")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_INCLUDEDIR "include")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_MANDIR "doc")
else()
    message( FATAL_ERROR "The PackageFormat is unknown")
endif()

################################
# compile of the module content
################################

list(APPEND testApp_sources
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
)

add_executable(${testApp}
    ${testApp_sources}
)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set_target_properties(${testApp} PROPERTIES
    LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
)

################################
# installation
################################
if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CPack.cmake")

    # install app
    install(
        TARGETS ${testApp}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_BINDIR}
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR}/static
    )

    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "test")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "test")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "xxx")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "xxx")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${PCK_MAJOR}")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${PCK_MINOR}")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "${PCK_REVISION}")
    set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${PrjName}_${PCK_MAJOR}.${PCK_MINOR}.${PCK_REVISION}")
    set(CPACK_SOURCE_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${PrjName}_${PCK_MAJOR}.${PCK_MINOR}.${PCK_REVISION}")

    include(CPack)
endif()
```

The cmake/STM32F2xx.cmake contains:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "--cpu Cortex-M3")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "--cpu Cortex-M3")
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS_INIT "--zt")
```

I created an toolchain file for the arm compiler:

```
# generated cmake toolchain file for
include (CMakeForceCompiler)

# We are cross compiling so we don't want compiler tests to run, as they will fail
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
# Set processor type
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

SET(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)

set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "arm-none-eabi-as.exe")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "arm-none-eabi-g++.exe")
set(CMAKE_LINKER "arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "mingw32-make.exe")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} --specs=nosys.specs")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --specs=nosys.specs")
```

When compiling on cmd with:

```
cd D:\git\myTestBuild\build
PATH=C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\6 2017-q1-update\bin;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DArch="STM32F2xx"  -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DPackageFormat=ZIP -DSWstackPath="D:\git\myTestBuild\SWstack" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="D:\git\myTestBuild\dump\toolchain.cmake"  ..

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6
  2017-q1-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple
  test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: D:/git/myTestBuild/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"C:/Program
  Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
  "cmTC_8c052/fast"

  C:/Program
  Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev2/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe
  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c052.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c052.dir/build

  mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory
  'D:/git/myTestBuild/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c052.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

  "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\6
  2017-q1-update\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" -o
  CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c052.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c
  D:\git\myTestBuild\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c

  Linking C executable cmTC_8c052

  "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c052.dir\link.txt --verbose=1

  "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\6
  2017-q1-update\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe"
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_8c052.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -o cmTC_8c052

  c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/6
  2017-q1-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-exit.o):
  In function `exit':

  exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'

  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

  CMakeFiles\cmTC_8c052.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'cmTC_8c052'
  failed

  mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [cmTC_8c052] Error 1

  mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
  'D:/git/myTestBuild/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  Makefile:125: recipe for target 'cmTC_8c052/fast' failed

  mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_8c052/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)
```

It fails. The compiler can't link the simple demo program because it does not find the "_exit" symbol. This problem should be overcome by [adding "--specs=nosys.specs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419782/exit-c-text0x18-undefined-reference-to-exit-when-using-arm-none-eabi-gcc). Seems that it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't append `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to in a toolchain file (since they are not yet defined). You can try using e.g. [`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) instead. Otherwise set [`CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE.html) to `STATIC_LIBRARY`.

Comment: since CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS can't be used to set the "--specs" parameter. I need an other solution set this parameter for compiling/linking at the toolchain/platform file

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

I've given a reduced version of your an example a try. I could reproduce your initial error and could fix the compiler detection by setting  [`CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE.html) to `STATIC_LIBRARY`. But then building an "executable" would still fail.

So you can set [`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT.html) to `--specs=nosys.specs` (since those are linker flags). Just **make sure** to start from an empty binary output directory if you are using `..._INIT` flags, since the resulting `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is cached.

I prefer to force the result `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable (`INTERNAL` does imply `FORCE`).

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project(testApp)

file(WRITE main.cpp "int main(void) { return 0; }")

set(testApp "testApp")

list(
    APPEND testApp_sources
        main.cpp
)

add_executable(
    ${testApp}
    ${testApp_sources}
)
```

**toolchain.cmake**

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "arm-none-eabi-g++.exe")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "--specs=nosys.specs" CACHE INTERNAL "")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

Does:

```
build> cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:PATH="..\toolchain.cmake"  ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM Embedded/6 2017-q1-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: build

build> cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target testApp
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testApp.dir/main.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable testApp
[100%] Built target testApp
```

**References**

- [cmake cross-compile with specific linker doesn't pass arguments to armlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313387/cmake-cross-compile-with-specific-linker-doesnt-pass-arguments-to-armlink)
- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)

Comment: What does CACHE INTERNAL "" mean? why is this necessary?

Comment: CACHE means to cache the value in CmakeCache.txt so that it gets preserved on subsequent runs of CMake even if not re-defined. INTERNAL means to hide it from visibility to the user in tools like cmake-gui.