# Clion (embedded development for stm32) CMake not found arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler

Tags: cmake, arm, stm32, clion, stm32cubemx

I made project like tutorial https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2019/02/clion-2019-1-eap-clion-for-embedded-development-part-iii/?gclid=CjwKCAjwhOD0BRAQEiwAK7JHmKUzvoJnORtCn3YxpsSb00Ep_dE0gNQOytiXVgFj6EXOjyCAIH9XTBoCngQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

I get arm toolchain from https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads

Add bin folder to PATH by .bashrc. Console command runs good:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc
arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

After make project in Clion with STM32CubeMX cmake not configure:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The ASM compiler identification is unknown
-- Found assembler: arm-none-eabi-gcc
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:34 (PROJECT):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    arm-none-eabi-gcc

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

But bin folder already in PATH!!!

Clion see compilers if install toolchail by pacman or copy all content of bin folder to /usr/bin/, but not found other files like nano.specs, nosys.specs, stdint.h and other includes.

I don't know how point Clion and CubeMX right path to toolchain.

Comment: "Add bin folder to PATH by .bashrc." - If I correctly remember, CLion doesn't use bash as a shell, so nothing is loading from `.bashrc` when CLion searches the compiler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43836115/532208

Comment: I also try edit PATH variable inside Clion in "Setting->Build,Execution,Deployment->Cmake" menu. I set in PATH full path to arm bins. But it didn't help.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/43836115/532208 - this is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your cmake cannot find C/C++ compiler.
In CLion Toolchain setting you can specify paths to compiler (arm-none-eabi-gcc and arm-none-eabi-g++ in your case) or just pass them to CMkae via `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` defines.

Comment: There is no effect to specify path in toolchain setting! Define CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER defines by by STM32CubeMX. If define CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER in environment of clion there is no effect too.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue.
I found that the reason is that Clion only uses the system environment variables at the time it was launched. The problem is most likely that you added ARM-related environment variables after Clion was launched, and the subsequent terminals used the environment variables from the launch.

The solution is to restart Clion.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+S and doublecheck your Toolchain and Cmake settings.

Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Toolchains:
Use absolute path to your build tool and compilers: [Setting Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqXVW.png)

Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> CMake:
Make sure you select the toolchain you created

Delete any previous cmake build folder.
Then Tools -> CMake -> Reset CMake Cache and Reload Project