# Cross compile with cmake cannot link test

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I try to cross compile a library ([Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)) using CMake (2.8.12.2). I get always errors which tell me that it is not able to compile a simple test program. 
I do not know how to make cmake to look into the right path for getting object files.
My development and target plattform is Linux.

The error log looks like this

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: /opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots/x86_64-rhlsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
Build flags: ;-O2;-pipe;-g;-feliminate-unused-debug-types;
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
/opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots/x86_64-rhlsdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi/5.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots/x86_64-rhlsdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi/5.3.0/real-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
...
```

Here is my tool chain file. I could skip the test (See CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS) but then I get later similar problems:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# Compiler and linker
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots/x86_64-rhlsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi-gcc")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots/x86_64-rhlsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi-g++")
SET(COMPILE_FLAGS " -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a8 --sysroot=/opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots/cortexa8hf-neon-reed-linux-gnueabi")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS " -O2 -v -o  --sysroot=/opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots/cortexa8hf-neon-reed-linux-gnueabi ")

# Paths
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots/cortexa8hf-neon-reed-linux-gnueabi/usr/)
SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT /opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots/cortexa8hf-neon-reed-linux-gnueabi/)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots/cortexa8hf-neon-reed-linux-gnueabi/)

SET(CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE ON)
set(SHARED_LIBS OFF)

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

# skip the compiler tests 
# set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1 CACHE INTERNAL "")
# set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1 CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

And here is a tree view of my system. I pruned it to show the relevant part.

```
/opt/rhl/0.01/sysroots
├── cortexa8hf-neon-reed-linux-gnueabi
│   ├── bin
│   ├── lib
│   ├── usr
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   ├── include
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   ├── crt1.o -> cmake cannot find this file
│   │   │   ├── crti.o -> cmake cannot find this file
│   │   ├── share
│   │   └── src
│   │           ├── gcc-runtime
│   │           │   └── 5.3.0-r0
└── x86_64-rhlsdk-linux
    ├── lib
    ├── sbin
    ├── usr
    │   ├── bin
    │   │   │   ├── arm-reed-linux-gcc -> ../arm-reed-linux-gnueabi/arm-reed-linux-gnueabi-gcc
    │   │   ├── arm-reed-linux-gnueabi
    │   │   │   ├── arm-reed-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -> The C compiler
    │   ├── include
    │   ├── lib
    │   ├── libexec
```

Comment: As you can see from error log, your compiler flags are not used. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536633/3440745) about proper setting compiler flags in toolchain. Also, setting [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) variable **automatically** provides `--sysroot` option for compiler, and given path is treated as one of *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH*. No needs to duplicate effects of sysroot.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake cross-compiling: C flags from toolchain file ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423313/cmake-cross-compiling-c-flags-from-toolchain-file-ignored)