# cmake cross compile can not find header file

Tags: cmake, openwrt

I want to cross compile **amazon Alexa SDK** in openwrt platform, but it can not find `curl/curl.h` when excute `make`, Here is my operate step:

1. create a cmake toolchain file like this:

   ```
   SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
   SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
   SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER  arm-openwrt-linux-muslgnueabi-gcc)
   SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  arm-openwrt-linux-muslgnueabi-g++)

   SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /home/sundq/workspace/Develop/out/astar-parrot/staging_dir/target/rootfs)

   SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT  /home/sundq/workspace/Develop/out/astar-parrot/staging_dir/target/rootfs)

   SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH  /home/sundq/workspace/Develop/out/astar-parrot/staging_dir/target/rootfs/usr/lib)

   SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
   SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
   SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

   SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-I/home/sundq/workspace/Develop/out/astar-parrot/staging_dir/target/rootfs/usr/include")

   SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-I/home/sundq/workspace/Develop/out/astar-parrot/staging_dir/target/rootfs/usr/include")
   ```
2. excute `cmake` like this:

   ```
   cmake ../avs-device-sdk-master-v1.0.2/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MINSIZEREL -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain.cmake
   ```
3. excute `make`, the output is:

   ```
   /AVSCommon/AVS/src/AlexaClientSDKInit.cpp:18:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
   ```

I'm sure the curl/curl.h file exist in `/home/sundq/workspace/Develop/out/astar-parrot/staging_dir/target/rootfs/usr/include` directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake cross-compiling: C flags from toolchain file ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423313/cmake-cross-compiling-c-flags-from-toolchain-file-ignored)

Comment: In short: you need to set **cached** variables *CMAKE_C_FLAGS* and *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS*.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to create an OpenWrt package for Alexa and add `libcurl` as a dependency.

Check [here](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/packages) in how to create a package.