# CMake toolchain file - setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS

Tags: c++, cmake

I have seen the following way of setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in the toolchain file:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-m32" CACHE STRING "C++ compiler flags" FORCE)
```

Should I use it in the toolchain file instead of

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m32")
```

?

What are differences between them ?

Comment: If you're the type of person that prefers `CMakeLists.txt` to contain only the minimum required to compile the project, another option to consider is setting them through [preset files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html).

Comment: Does the second way - without CACHE - ever work inside a **toolchain**? According to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423313/cmake-cross-compiling-c-flags-from-toolchain-file-ignored), it is not.

Comment: The second way works. Tested using cmake 3.23.2. Builded binaries have been verified using ```file``` command.

Comment: The second way does _not_ work in general. It is in fact very broken. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*tl;dr: there are two acceptable ways of doing this.*

First, and most of the time (90%+), you can use the `_INIT` variables as [suggested by the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_INIT.html):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-m32")
```

Second, if CMake is adding incorrect/conflicting flags for your compiler/platform combination, you can override it completely by setting the cache variable *without* `FORCE`.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-m32" CACHE STRING "C++ compiler flags")
```

Read on for further details.

---

Let's run a few experiments. We'll use the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(test LANGUAGES CXX)

message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
```

On most systems, CMake leaves `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` blank by default. The main exception is Windows with MSVC, where it adds `/EHsc` and (on older versions) `/GR` to ensure that standard C++ exception handling and RTTI are enabled.

Since I don't have ready access to a Windows system, I use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`, which *does* have default-initialized flags on most compilers. The same principles apply, though, since it is the responsibility of the platform module to set these in both cases.

### Experiment 1: No toolchain file

```
$ cmake -S . -B build
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -g
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/build
```

So on this compiler, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` is set to `-g`. This is our baseline.

### Experiment 2: Set-cache with force

Now we'll create a toolchain file called `set-cache-force.cmake`:

```
# set-cache-force.cmake
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-DMY_DEBUG" CACHE STRING "C++ compiler flags" FORCE)
```

We'll configure the project with this toolchain:

```
$ rm -rf build
$ cmake -S . -B build --toolchain set-cache-force.cmake 
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -DMY_DEBUG
...
```

As we can see, the original `-g` flag was suppressed and the `-DMY_DEBUG` cache value "won". Of course, this isn't really a debug mode anymore, which should illustrate why overriding all the flags isn't always what we want.

Even worse, using `FORCE` here disables a user's ability to override `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` themselves:

```
$ rm -rf build
$ cmake -S . -B build --toolchain set-cache-force.cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-DOVERRIDE"
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -DMY_DEBUG
...
```

This is highly undesirable behavior. A user would need to edit your toolchain file to work around a bug or add further customizations.

### Experiment 3: Set-cache *without* force

If we run the same experiment as before without `FORCE` setting it, then we still get the same flags, but we retain the ability to incrementally override the toolchain file.

```
# set-cache.cmake
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-DMY_DEBUG" CACHE STRING "C++ compiler flags")
```

Now we can see that it works:

```
$ rm -rf build
$ cmake -S . -B build --toolchain set-cache.cmake
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -DMY_DEBUG
...
```

And that it can still be overridden:

```
$ rm -rf build
$ cmake -S . -B build --toolchain set-cache.cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-DOVERRIDE"
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -DOVERRIDE
...
```

And it can even be overridden again:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-DOVERRIDE2"
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -DOVERRIDE2
...
```

### Experiment 4: Set normal variable

Now we'll try to set this as a normal variable. Again, we'll create a toolchain file called `set-normal.cmake`:

```
# set-normal.cmake
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-DMY_DEBUG")
```

Again, running this shows that `-DMY_DEBUG` "wins", overriding CMake's default flags:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build --toolchain set-normal.cmake
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -DMY_DEBUG
...
```

Like experiment 2, this prevents users from overriding it... bad!

```
$ cmake -S . -B build --toolchain set-normal.cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-DOVERRIDE"
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -DMY_DEBUG
...
```

### Experiment 5: Append normal variable

Now we'll try with the code in your post. Again, we'll use a toolchain called `append-normal.cmake`:

```
# append-normal.cmake
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DMY_DEBUG")
```

Now we get a very different result:

```
$ rm -rf build
$ cmake -S . -B build --toolchain append-normal.cmake
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG =  -DMY_DEBUG -DMY_DEBUG
...
```

**This is just completely wrong!** What happened here? Well, the toolchain file gets read multiple times during project initialization, and here this causes the `-DMY_DEBUG` flag to be appended twice. At least that's what happens on the *first* run:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -g -DMY_DEBUG
...
```

After the first run, the CMake default gets cached and so we append to that on subsequent runs. Furthermore, CMake only reads your toolchain file once now.

**You must always make your toolchain files idempotent.** That means that running it twice does the same thing as running it once.

### Experiment 6: Using `_INIT` variables

**This is the developer-intended way of doing things per the documentation**. See the documentation here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_INIT.html

> Value used to initialize the `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` cache entry the first time a build tree is configured for language `<LANG>`. This variable is meant to be set by a toolchain file. CMake may prepend or append content to the value based on the environment and target platform.

Now we use a toolchain file called `init-var.cmake`:

```
# init-var.cmake
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "-DMY_DEBUG")
```

And we re-run the build:

```
$ rm -rf build
$ cmake -S . -B build --toolchain init-var.cmake
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -DMY_DEBUG -g
...
```

Now we can see that CMake appended its default flags to the initial ones we provided. And indeed this still allows users to override things:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build --toolchain init-var.cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-DOVERRIDE"
...
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG = -DOVERRIDE
...
```

---

In my experience, 90%+ of the time it's correct to let CMake add in its extra flags using Experiment 6 (the `_INIT` variables). But every so often you'll want to completely override CMake using Experiment 3 (`set(CACHE)` *without* `FORCE`).

What you do *not* want to do is anything that behaves differently on subsequent runs (like experiment 5) or that disables key CMake functionality (ie. respecting the cache variable, like experiments 2 and 4).

Answer (score -1):

When you use `set(variable "value" CACHE STRING "..." FORCE)`, the variable is set for all the projects built in the current session (including those that are in the sub-directories).

But simply using `set(variable "value")` without the cache part only adds the flags for the immediate project scope (current CMakeLists.txt) and not the upper directories that have their own CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Your comment is outdated.