# MySQL Connector/C BAD ACCESS crash (another situation)

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access, mysql-connector, xcode4.6

I'm sorry for such a noob question, but I can't win the fight with my Xcode (4.6.1) while compiling the simplest program to connect to MySQL database and perform the "SELECT" command there.

The program is from "examples" directory of MySQL Connector/C++:

```
/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

std::string url;
std::string user;
std::string pass;
std::string database;

/**
 * Usage example for Driver, Connection, (simple) Statement, ResultSet
 */
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    sql::Driver *driver;
    std::auto_ptr< sql::Connection > con;

    url = "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306";
    user = "john";
    pass = "john";
    database = "cunda_sales";

    try {
        driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();

        /* Using the Driver to create a connection */
        con.reset(driver->connect(url, user, pass));
        con->setSchema(database);

        sql::Statement* stmt = con->createStatement();
        stmt->execute("INSERT INTO ru (store_name) values ('Test is successful')");
    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After I run that program in Xcode I get the message that program compiled successful, but it stops running when calling:

```
driver->connect(url, user, pass)
```

giving me an error

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address=0x0)
```

Almost the same situation was described here: [here on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570347/mysql-connector-c-bad-access-crash)

I repeated all the steps those guys were followed through, but I can't do anything with that mistake. I also tried to compile the program in my terminal with the following command:

```
c++ -o test -I /usr/local/boost_1_53_0 -lmysqlcppconn main.cpp
```

and everything works just fine, but NOT in Xcode.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570347/mysql-connector-c-bad-access-crash) the solution was found, but sorry for my stupidness, I just don't know what I need to do in/with my Xcode to make it compile the program in a proper way to work.

Guys wrote there that the problem was in -stdlib=libc++ flag, which Xcode useв for compiling the code. So what should I do to avoid that mistake? Delete that flag from Xcode compiler or use another compiler? Or should I just need to recompile the MySQL Connector/C++ with this flag?

Please explain me the final solution. Thank you!

Comment: This will perhaps seem an odd question. Where is your sqlite runtime, and more importantly, the *driver* you're loading when you run your program? I ask because you mentioned when you build *and run* from the command line everything runs fine, but not from Xcode. You may just be missing the proper working directory setup from your Xcode Run-environment. As it stands now, the violation is clearly because the driver instance is not properly loaded.

Comment: I'm sorry for such a question, I know it's silly, but it's my first time of trying to write a code on C++ and using Xcode. I'm a web programmer and never been studied C++ before, that's why I ask here. I would be really glad if you can help me to compare environment of c++ compiler and Xcode. Thanks.