# Errors trying to link MySQL to a project

Tags: c++, mysql-connector, xcode4.6

I'm not sure if I should have divided this into two posts... if so, let me know for future reference. For now, there are problems with both static and dynamic linking, and I'll put noticeable text to divide the two.

I've looked all over the place and found A LOT of solutions both here and elsewhere that seems to solve the problems for others... but none of these solutions have worked for me.

Ahead of time, I downloaded Boost and it didn't seem to come with a library - and make doesn't do anything to the directory it's in (Not a fan of Terminal, but I've had to `./configure && make`, `make` and `make install` a few things recently; Boost doesn't seem to do anything with any of this).

I'm already using SDL and my own static library. MySQL Connector/C++ doesn't require either, of course. It does, however, require Boost.

## Static

Originally, I attempted to statically link the MySQL library, but that failed horribly by giving me a long list of errors (109 to be exact - all linkers). I'd prefer static linking if it's possible, so I'll list some of the errors here:

```
"std::istream::gcount() const", referenced from:
 sql::mysql::LongDataSender::operator()(std::istream*) const in libMySQL.a(mysql_prepared_statement.cpp.o)
"std::string::find_last_of(char, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
  sql::mysql::parseUri(sql::SQLString const&, sql::mysql::MySQL_Uri&) in libMySQL.a(mysql_uri.cpp.o)
"std::string::find_first_of(char, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
  sql::mysql::MySQL_ConnectionMetaData::getTablePrivileges(sql::SQLString const&, sql::SQLString const&, sql::SQLString const&) in libMySQL.a(mysql_metadata.cpp.o)
"std::string::find(std::string const&, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
  sql::mysql::MySQL_ConnectionMetaData::getColumnPrivileges(sql::SQLString const&, sql::SQLString const&, sql::SQLString const&, sql::SQLString const&) in libMySQL.a(mysql_metadata.cpp.o)
  sql::mysql::MySQL_ConnectionMetaData::getIdentifierQuoteString() in libMySQL.a(mysql_metadata.cpp.o)
...
sql::SQLString, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>, std::less<sql::SQLString>, 
std::allocator<std::pair<sql::SQLString const, boost::variant<int, double, bool, 
sql::SQLString, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,   
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, 
boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_> > > >&) in 
libMySQL.a(mysql_connection.cpp.o)
...
```

For statically linking, some of the solutions I've read have included the thoughts of… perhaps the library isn't being linked. One solution recommended linking to libstdc++. These were pretty much the two most widely-claimed solutions, but I'm definitely linking the library and libstdc++ didn't effect the errors at all.

## Dynamic

So, when, after close to nine hours of trying to get the static-link errors to go away, I decided to move over to dynamic library... all the linker errors were gone! Content enough, I tried to run it and...

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlcppconn.7.dylib
Referenced from: /.../Example.app/Contents/MacOS/Example
Reason: image not found
```

... Wonderful. My first instinct was, "Oh, right, I need to copy it into the bundle." So, naturally, I went to check on that. Did it. Ran again. No change. Today, I found a few solutions: Go to the Xcode directory and delete Derived Data folder and try to run it again. No luck. The only solution I didn't try (Because I don't think I can) was changing the install path for the dylib.

When I was searching for an answer to the static library issue, one person mentioned that the connector from MySQL's site had this problem, but the (Assumably same) connector from a different site didn't have the issue. Problem: A link wasn't given.

Some frequent claimed solutions when these problems come up:

- Header path isn't listed in project settings, so the methods being
  called can't be found.
- Close Xcode, delete Derived Data in the xCode directory, open project, build.
- Might be using a 32-bit library on a 64-bit project, or vice versa.
- Dynamic library isn't being copied to the bundle.
- Library isn't in the link list.
- Should clean and then build.

Now... out of this list, I've checked to make sure they're all as correct as I know how to get them, and as mentioned earlier, I've already downloaded Boost. Yes, I've made sure the header and lib paths are included in the project settings, same with MySQL's.

... Anyone have ANY idea what the deal might be? I've also started a brand new Cocoa project and attempted to get MySQL to work with just connecting to a database and nothing else, and the results are the same (Static and dynamic both).

I’m using Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.6.2.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I'm getting the exact same error... Apparently when I look at the directory that I got from mysql connector c++ in the download, libmysqlcppconn.7.dylib was just a pointer (alias) to libmysqlcppconn.7.1.1.3.dylib.

Answer (score 3):

For the dynamic linking I think you had the same problem as me. When I compiled I specified that the library was in another folder

```
g++ -I /opt/local/include/ -I /opt/local/include/mysql55-connector-cpp/driver/ -I /opt/local/include/mysql55-connector-cpp/cppconn/ -L libs/ -l mysqlcppconn db_layer.cpp
```

When you actually run the file you need the libmysqlcppconn.7.dylib library ( be careful that the name is exactly like this ) to be in the same folder with your executable.

Comment: This helped me.  The key is to move the dylib file to the same build directory where Xcode is creating your binary.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue that you're describing here, unfortunately, as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570347/mysql-connector-c-bad-access-crash), even if you do get it to compile, it won't link properly, and you'll have to compile it yourself using the right compiler flags. That said, once you've got an executable compiled correctly, you can use the tools described in [this page](http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/08/11/embedding-frameworks-in-loadable-bundles/) to tell it to look in your Frameworks folder for the dyld.

I wish you the best of luck.